# jquery $('a').each not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a querystring onto all links on a page, I've added this code to get it done but as you can see, it's not working
http://yamputours.staging.wpengine.com/?why=broken

```
var querystring = location.search;
console.log(querystring);

$('a').each(function() {
    console.log('working');
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href) {
        href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    }
});
```

I don't get any thing in the console from the second `console.log()`.

I get that the code inside it still needs modification to not break on things like `href='#'` but even when I cut out all the code inside the function except the `console.log('working);` O get nothing from it.  This is driving me crazy, can anyone see what I'm missing?

FYI there is a ton of other jQuery on this site and in the same file as this even, all of it works fine, just not this one function.

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: the whole thing is inside a .js file wrapped in `(function( $ ) {....}(jQuery));`

Comment: moved it out and tried using `jQuery('a')` just in case.  still no go.

Comment: From what I can read, the code above is executed before the DOM has been loaded. Hence you see the first log message, but not the one in the loop.

Comment: The referenced page has a lot of script tags, where did you hide the `$('a').each` code? I cannot find it... Could you instead create a small fiddle that reproduces the issue, but only has the relevant code?

Comment: it's in the yampu.js fileI think fredrik might be on to something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code adding in **$(document).ready(function() {** function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + ' working');
  });

  console.log('---By class selector---')
  $('.link').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + ' working with class "link"');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test1">test 1</a>
<a href="#test2">test 2</a>
<a href="#test3">test 3</a>
<a href="#test4">test 4</a> // second option with class
<a href="#test5" class="link">test 5</a>
<a href="#test6" class="link">test 6</a>
<a href="#test7" class="link">test 7</a>
<a href="#test8" class="link">test 8</a>
```

Comment: Thanks SwapNeil!  Couldn't see the forest through the trees!